# Spring Data JPA - Get all elements

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I'm new to Spring Data JPA and I want to ask if there is a method that can be used to fetch all items, not by a certain criterion. Any help would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the findAll method from repository

```
repository.findAll()
```

Take a look here

[Spring Data JPA API](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html)

Look here a small example that will fetch all MyObj objects that are stored

```
@Repository
public interface MyObjRepository extends JpaRepository<MyObj, Long> { }

@Service
public class MyService {

@Autowired
MyObjRepository repository;

public List<MyObj> findAllElements() {
  return repository.findAll();
 }

}
```